# MapReduce Code to find the maximum temperature of city

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Problem Statement : Find the max temperature of each city using MapReduce

Input:

```
Kolkata,56
Jaipur,45
Delhi,43
Mumbai,34
Goa,45
Kolkata,35
Jaipur,34
Delhi,32
```

Output:

```
Kolkata   56
Jaipur    45
Delhi     43
Mumbai    34
```

I have written the following code :

Map:

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class Map 
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private IntWritable max = new IntWritable();
    private Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(),",\t");

        word.set(line.nextToken());
        max.set(Integer.parseInt(line.nextToken()));

        context.write(word,max);            

        }
    }
```

Reduce:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class Reduce 
        extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

    private int max_temp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int temp = 0;

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, 
            Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Iterator<IntWritable> itr = values.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {

            temp = itr.next().get();
            if( temp > max_temp)
            {
                max_temp = temp;
            }
        }

        context.write(key, new IntWritable(max_temp));
    }
}
```

Driver Class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MaxTempDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        

        // Create a new job
        Job job = new Job();

        // Set job name to locate it in the distributed environment
        job.setJarByClass(MaxTempDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("Max Temperature");

        // Set input and output Path, note that we use the default input format
        // which is TextInputFormat (each record is a line of input)
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        // Set Mapper and Reducer class
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        // Set Output key and value
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
17/06/15 10:44:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : 
attempt_201706151011_0002_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at Map.map(Map.java:23)
at Map.map(Map.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
atorg.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

As you can see, I am getting java.util.NoSuchElementException in the map function. Please help me with this exception and provide your suggestions to modify the map() code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the next token exists:

```
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",\t");

    if (line.countTokens() > 0) {
        word.set(line.nextToken());

        if (line.hasMoreTokens())
            max.set(Integer.parseInt(line.nextToken()));

        context.write(word, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the OP is using `while (itr.hasNext())` in the reducer, but the exception is being thrown in the mapper, where the OP is not checking whether the next token is available.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I noticed when I tried out this particular example of MapReduce is that, the highest value gets cascaded for all the values following the place with the highest temperature.

Output looked something similar to this,

```
Delhi   43
Goa     45
Jaipur  45
Kolkata 56
Mumbai  56
```

As opposed to this,

```
Delhi   43
Goa     45
Jaipur  45
Kolkata 56
Mumbai  34
```

You can see that the last value of Mumbai has a temperature of 56(which is the highest temperature for Kolkata)

I noticed that, this was because of not resetting the temp and the max_temperature for each call of the reduce function.

Adding the following two lines inside the reduce function within the Reduce class, just before the while loop solves this issue,

```
temp = 0;
max_temp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```